# What data structure in JS would allows to choose one value from defined values?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, metaprogramming, dynamic-programming

I want to create status object. Which can have values like `pending`, `session`, `rejected`, `cancelled`...

I want to access it like `status.isSession();`, `status.isPending()`... etc`

but i want to assign it like this `status.toPending();` , `status.toSession();`

This way there is no room for spelling errors.

I think this is dynamic programming.

Comment: Why do you need it to be accessible that way. Can't you just have e.g. `status.get()` and `status.set(status.inprogress)`?

Comment: "im open to status.session() if i dont have to define function separately for each status" What do you mean by that ? @FCin's solution would allow you to achieve this with only one function, you take the new status and pass it as an argument to `set` and then you set that argument to true and all the other objects to false.

Comment: I updated question

Comment: @MuhammadUmer The requirement at the updated Question is different from the requirement at text of original Question, yes? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no i made it clear

Comment: The value that is set by the function call is not relevant to the requirement?

Comment: isABC returns true or false depending if value is ABC or not. toABC sets the value to ABC

Comment: It's only "dynamic programming" or meta-programming if you're not writing those methods yourself, which you could just do. Is the issue that you have an *arbitrary* list of possible statuses? I mean, just write the methods that query the internal value.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in JavaScript, but it will work only with double equals.

You can create an object with constructor like this :

```
function Status(value){
  this.session = true;
  this.value = value;
}
```

Now if you create an instance of this object :

```
const status = new Status('session');
```

Sure enough status.session will return true and status.value will return 'session.'

Now you can override toString() method of this object so it returns status.value

```
Status.prototype.toString = function(){
  return this.value;
}
```

The reason for this is that, when you try to compare an Object vs Primitive, the Engine will try to put them in 'value context' and coerce your object to String by calling `.toString()` operation.

Sure enough this will produce :

```
const status = new Status('session');
console.log(status == 'session');
```

A true in your console.

***But this is highly discouraged because is a hack and you might get weird bugs, so I suggest to stay away.***